# WordPress get specific posts in arbitrary order

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, post, sql-order-by

Right now, I'm doing:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array(1, 3, 2, 9, 7)));
```

and am having two issues:

1. Post 3 is of `'post_type' => 'post'`, so it doesn't get selected, but I want it! If I leave out `'post_type' => 'page'`, then only post 3 is selected (because it must assume 'post_type' => 'post'.).
2. I want to be able to [order the posts arbitrarily by their ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327159/mysql-specify-arbitrary-order-by-id). If I knew how to use MySQL, I could do:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (1, 3, 2, 9, 7)
   ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID, '1,3,2,9,7');
   ```

But, how should I do this with [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Kawauso on the #wordpress IRC channel informed me that "post_type takes an array of values." From that, I found that the following also selects post 3:
2. So, I did the following:

   ```
   $post_ids = array(1 => 0, 3 => 1, 2 => 2, 9 => 3, 7 => 4);
   $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
                            'post__in' => array_keys($post_ids)));
   $ordered_posts = array(0,0,0,0,0); // size of five; keeps order
   foreach ($posts as $p) {
     setup_postdata($p);
     $ordered_posts[$post_ids[$p->ID]] = array(
       'permalink' => get_permalink($p->ID),
       'title' => $p->post_title,
       'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
       'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($p->post_date)));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First fetch all posts arbitrarily by their ids and then loop through all the posts

You can do in this way:-

```
$posts=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID IN (1, 3, 2, 9, 7)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID, '1,3,2,9,7')");
$count=count($posts);
for ($counter=0 ; $counter < $count; $counter++)
{
   $post=get_post( $posts[$counter]->ID, $output );
  //do your stuffs with posts
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This would work, but I think you're doing excessive SQL queries. AFAIK, `get_post` does an SQL query. So, you could just replace the first line with `$order => array(1, 3, 2, 9, 7)`. But then you'd still be doing five SQL queries, one for each post, Also, `foreach` is faster & cleaner in this & most cases. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329800/wordpress-get-specific-posts-in-arbitrary-order/4337226#4337226).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-post-order?replies=6), you can use this code and then use the classic WordPress loop:

```
$args = array(  
'post_type'=>'page',  
    'orderby'=>'menu_order',  
    'order'=>'ASC'  
);  
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: This is good to know, but in this case, they are not all pages, and I think they're in a different order than menu order.