# Select entries where one column is "val", then "aaa", then "ccc"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

How to order entries by one column (let's say named `column13`). First should be entries where `column13` is "val", then "aaa", then "ccc". I can't use `GROUP BY column13 ASC` or similar. Is it possible to do it without writing 3 queries?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327159/mysql-specify-arbitrary-order-by-id work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `FIELD()` construct available in MySQL:

```
SELECT       stuff
    FROM     table
    WHERE    condition
    ORDER BY FIELD(column13, 'val', 'aaa', 'ccc')
```

Comment: "It's not that I'm a good comedian, it's that some people are just so easily amused." - Ron White