# I want to pull data from an array in specific sequence using FIND_IN how?--never recived a right answer

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Below is my code and I want to pull the data based on the sequence 3, 10 then 7, how can I do that? so far it pulls first 10, then 7, then 3.

```
        $cars = $this->car->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'car.id' => array(3, 10, 7)
        ),
        'limit' => 3, 
        'order' => array('car.id' => 'desc')
    ));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL specify arbitrary order by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327159/mysql-specify-arbitrary-order-by-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do the conditions come from? Anyway i believe this will work:

```
    $cars = $this->car->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'car.id' => array(3, 10, 7)
    ),
    'limit' => 3, 
    'order' => array('FIELD(car.id,3,10,7)')
));
```

Might need to play around with the cakePHP specific syntax, but the `ORDER BY FIELD(fieldname, value, value value);` should work

Comment: That's my problem, I need the right syntex, I am still receiving errors as  Call to undefined function FIELD() or syntax error, unexpected 'car' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: @Dani yeah sorry should be `'FIELD(car.id,3,10,7)'`. no quotes around car.id

Comment: Also its not specific to the question you asked. Normal cake convention would be to capitalize the first letter of the model name. I think `car.id` should be `Car.id` and `$this->Car->find(...`. would want to name the model class as `class Car extends AppModel`